# Updating UI for JTextArea in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextarea

I'm a beginner and I've hit a bump in the road.

The problem I have is that my `JTextArea` is not updating as my program is running. I ran a command line to see whether the value of the `JTextArea` is changing. It turns out that it is but on the UI it remains the same until the end, then it shows the final change that I had made. Could you please help me find a solution to this problem?

Here follows the code where the problem arises. (In my `ActionListener`.)

```
private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener   //Start of inner class for event handling of buttons
{
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
        {//start method that prosesses the events for the buttons

            if(event.getSource() == call)
            {
                do {
                    delay.myDelay(2000); //simply a Thread.sleep(I intend to repeat this a lot so I made a class for it.

                    elevatorFloor = eCall.calling();
                    eCall.setFloor(elevatorFloor);
                    System.out.println("getfloor in call= " +eCall.getFloor()); //Test yields correct value

                    eFloor = ind.level(eCall.getFloor()); //String that gives floor number
                    floorIndicator.setText(eFloor); //DOES NOT CHANGE IN GUI

                    String value = floorIndicator.getText();
                    System.out.println("Floorindicator is= " +value);//Test yields that the value  is changing dynamically in command line

                    floorIndicator.updateUI();  //Stuff I found on the internet that didnt work
                    floorIndicator.revalidate();
                    floorIndicator.validate();


                } while(eCall.getFloor() != eCall.getUserFloor());

                    delay.myDelay(2000);

                    doorImage.setIcon(door1);
                }
           }
      }
```

Comment: Sorry first time user. Please explain what you mean by Use swingWorker. As I said, beginner

Comment: Why are you doing this: `floorIndicator.revalidate();
     floorIndicator.validate();`

Comment: Stuff I found on the internet that I that I saw other people do. Didnt understand it myself. But tried it to see if it would work. DID NOT work

Comment: If you remove the `do...while` sections, thus making your code run once and get rid of the `delay.myDelay(2000)` method, would it work?

Comment: Tried it now. It defeats the purpose. When I press the button I want to go to certain floor (In this case the user floor). If i remove the loop it means I have to constantly press the button. The delay is to make sure that it doesnt go from the level its at to the userfloor in instantaneously

Comment: You are blocking EDIT, use [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)

Comment: The purpose of my comment wasn't to provide a solution, but rather to understand the problem. `Thread.sleep` is something which you should never do within an Event Handler. Having loops sometimes also makes it more difficult to see what is happening. Does your code change the value of the TextArea when you remove the loops and pause statements?

Comment: Yes it does, and it displays it in the GUI. I already verified this by checking using the command line with the loop and delay, it just doesnt change it in the GUI. 

Where should I use it the thread.sleep() then?

Comment: @KeagonLouw: Please check the answer below, hopefully it will shed some light on the matter.

Comment: @KeagonLouw: You're welcome. Once you get the hang of the EDT Swing will become easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, the UI (drawing of components, events, etc) is handled by a special thread called the [Event Dispatching Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). Since this thread determines how quickly will your UI respond to events, it is important that you do only UI related operations on it.

Doing operations which might be blocking, such as `Thread.sleep` are not recommended to be done in this thread since it blocks the execution of the thread and thus makes your application not respond to events in a timely manner. This is why in some of the comments, you where told that you are blocking the EDT.

In you case, looping can also be avoided since with each iteration, you are waiting for a period of two seconds (I am assuming to give the impression of the escalator moving between floors).

The solution to this, (one of them at least), would be to place the entire body of the `do...while` loop in a separate thread. This thread will be then launched by the event handler. This solution would not block the event dispatching thread, but now there is another problem: Only the EDT can upload the UI, thus, the approach above on its own would not change the text.

For this purpose, Java provides a [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) class which allows code to queue items on the EDT.

Thus in short, your code would like something like so:

```
private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener   //Start of inner class for event handling of buttons
{
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
        {//start method that prosesses the events for the buttons

            if(event.getSource() == call)
            {
                //final int elFloor = eCall.calling(); i ran it without this and it worked
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        do{
                        /*There is nothing wrong with calling Thread.sleep directly
                         *wrapping a one liner with your own implementation might cause
                         *more confusion
                         */                     
                        delay.myDelay(2000);

                        //Not sure what is elevatorFloor
                        elevatorFloor = eCall.calling();
                        eCall.setFloor(elevatorFloor);
                        System.out.println("getfloor in call= " +eCall.getFloor()); //Test yields correct value

                        eFloor = ind.level(eCall.getFloor()); //String that gives floor number
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                floorIndicator.setText(eFloor); //DOES NOT CHANGE IN GUI
                            }
                        });


                        String value = floorIndicator.getText();
                        System.out.println("Floorindicator is= " +value);//Test yields that the value  is changing dynamically in command line

                        }while(eCall.getFloor() != eCall.getUserFloor());

                        //delay.myDelay(2000);

                        doorImage.setIcon(door1);
                    }
                }).start();
            }
       }
}
```

Note: The code above has not been tested and you might need to make additional changes, especially on how you can access the variables from within the thread scopes, but it should provide an overview of what you need to do.